# laravel8 how to replace file original name with two requested inputs names

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code that changes the file's original name to the custom name from my form. I would also like to add another request in order for my file name to be composed out of 2 inputs.

```
 if ($request->hasFile('talonphoto')){
                $extension = $request->file('talonphoto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $photoName = str_replace('','', $request->name). '_'. time(). '.' .$extension;
                $request->file('talonphoto')->move('image/documentemasini', $photoName);
                $tagacars->talonphoto = $photoName;
            }
```

This is the code, so in order for me to change the name with two inputs would it be something similar to this?

```
if ($request->hasFile('talonphoto')){
                $extension = $request->file('talonphoto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $photoName = str_replace('','', $request->name, $request->talondata0). '_'. time(). '.' .$extension;
                $request->file('talonphoto')->move('image/documentemasini', $photoName);
                $tagacars->talonphoto = $photoName;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not put to string in **str_replace** function.
Try this code:

```
$photoName = str_replace('','', $request->name). '_'.str_replace('','', $request->talondata0).'_'. time(). '.' .$extension;
```

Answer (score 1):

1st way you can concatenate two string request.

```
$photoName = str_replace('','', $request->name.$request->talondata0). '_'. time(). '.' .$extension;
```

2nd way you can use str_replace individual

```
$photoName = str_replace('','', $request->name). '_'.str_replace('','', $request->talondata0).'_'. time(). '.' .$extension;
```

Also use this in controller before the controller class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```